# What colours have already been used in Gmail compose?

Tags: gmail, gmail-text-editor

When composing an email in Gmail I colour some parts of the text.

Sometimes I'd like to know what colour I've used earlier in the email.

Is there a way to see this? Some other inline editors allow you to see the underlying HTML and you can derive the colour from that but not, as far as I can see, in Gmail.

I wondered if there was some sort of addon which might do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Chrome browser, select that earlier mail and right-click and select "inspect element". Check the HTML code of corresponding block.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a picture to let the OP see where he/she needs to be?

Comment: This would seem to be too late, no? The OP is asking about figuring this out while composing the message. Going back to an "earlier mail" implies the messages was composed and sent (or at least a draft).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about finding the same color in an email you haven't sent yet, can't you just click the text in the email and open the color palette again?

If you type one or more words in a different color, putting the cursor back in that set of words and clicking on the color palette will show you what the currently selected color is.